# How to deploy JavaSpaces on two computers?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, javaspaces

I successfully installed JavaSpace on Ubuntu, tried one example and it worked. Now I don't know how to deploy JavaSpace on other Ubuntu and use it like JavaSpace node. I installed JavaSpace on the second Ubuntu but now what? Two Ubuntu machines are on the same network..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the javaspaces are registering themselves with a registrar (reggie) and your network passes multicast thru the router it should just 'work'.

Comment: how could i check if javaspaces are registering themselves with a registar? What is registar?

Comment: http://www.kedwards.com/jini/reggie.html
http://www.artima.com/javaseminars/modules/Jini/index.html